# Configure Keycloak to include an at_hash claim in the id token

Tags: go, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm currently using Keycloak 9.0.0. When authenticating using the code flow and exchanging this code, I'm receiving an id token without the `at_hash` claim.

How do I configure Keycloak to include an `at_hash` claim in the id token?

Background:

I'm using a "classic" server side rendered (SSR) program, a confidential client.
I'm sending requests to my local http api. But I also have an Angular client. The SSR is a Go programm using github.com/coreos/go-oidc.
Rendered pages that require authentication redirect the visitor to keycloak and back via the redirect_uri.
Since the visitor is logged in its id token is present in the session and I also pass the access token. However the id token has no `at_hash` claim and thus access token validation fails.

I also have a mobile web version of this site, in Angular and it sends a bearer access token once logged in. This app uses the code flow + pcke.

Both should be able to send authenticated requests, but since I'm using pretty much the only oidc client library for Go available, it requires an `at_hash` claim being present in the id token to be able to verify access tokens. The package currently has no support for the introspection endpoint.

Both id token and access token are returned from the IDP. But neither has an `at_hash` claim.

Comment: Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. What Pawel.S. wrote is the hybrid flow, which implies implicit flow, which is disabled in my client configuration. There is no other way than the code flow when using coreos/go-oidc. My solution for this particular problem is to split off the RESTful http api and add a keycloak-gatekeeper in front of it. For the SSR website I will just check if session values are present. It's not possible to provide both from the same listening port since there is no way to verify the authenticity of the access token with coreos/go-oidc.

Answer (score 1):

According to [OIDC](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitIDToken) `at_hash` is mandatory only when access token is issued.
Make sure you are using `response_type=id_token token` and not `response_type=id_token`.

Comment: Like I wrote, it's using the code flow, not the implicit flow.

Comment: It's also returning both id token and access token without `at_hash`

Comment: Then use `response_type=code id_token token`
Please, check examples [OIDC](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthorizationExamples)

Comment: Hybrid flow (`code id_token token`) is not supported by this client library. The spec you linked describes the hybrid flow (code + implicit). Implicit flow is not used, it's also deactivated for the kc client. My question is about forcing Keycloak to include the `at_hash` claim in the id token. Thank you for the hint though.